# Youtube embed list in website video links go to different page

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api

I have a website with the embed youtube video list and the several videos loads as a list inside a iframe. I used ytchannelembed to generate this section(code).

My issue is individual video link is not going to the Youtube channel instead it is going to ytchannelembed page and play the video inside that page. How to make it goes to Youtube page and play the video.

Appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use the embed code that youtube gives you instead of using a third party app that is obviously trying to get traffic through your embed code.

Comment: I wanted have something like this 
http://www.defencejobs.gov.au/?gclid=CKG7j9-iudACFZaWvQodoHQDhA&gclsrc=aw.ds
Go to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Thomas Please see the image I just added.

Comment: Because it is in an iframe the ytchannelembed is controlling the functionality. You will have to build this yourself if you want it to work any other way. There may even be other services similar to this out there, or, if it is CMS enabled website you can try any number of plugins.

Comment: Yes. I'm also thinking to create custom widget like this. Thanks for the information.